# Lit Element VSCode plugin Unknown attribute 'frameborder'

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, visual-studio-code, lit-element

I'm using an iframe in the template of a lit element and the lit element VSCode plugin draws this errors:

> Unknown attribute 'frameborder'. Did you mean '.frameBorder'?
> This is a built in tag. Please consider using a 'data-*' attribute, adding the attribute to 'globalAttributes' or disabling the 'no-unknown-attribute' rule.lit-plugin(no-unknown-attribute)(2318)

Anyone know if it's possible to tell the plugin to ignore the attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this:

> This error indicates that your lit-html template references a tag that
> the lit-analyzer can’t resolve.
>
> There must be a declaration of the element to TypeScript in order for
> the analyzer to find it. For example:
>
> ```
> export class FancySlider extends HTMLElement {
>   value: number;
>   // etc...
> }
> customElements.define('fancy-slider', FancySlider);
>
> declare global {
>   interface HTMLElementTagNameMap {
>     'fancy-slider': FancySlider,
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> How to fix it Three conditions must hold:
>
> 1. There must be a type for the element in TypeScript, either because the
>    code for the element is written in TpeScript, or because there are
>    TypeScript typings for the element.
> 2. The type must be associated with
>    the element’s tagname in the HTMLElementTagNameMap.
> 3. The file where
>    you’re using the element must depend on the declaration of the
>    element, generally by importing it. Most commonly, you’re just missing
>    an import for the element. If you’re importing the element, and your
>    code works at runtime, then you need to define an interface for the
>    element, and add it to the HTMLElementTagNameMap.
>
> How it’s configured
>
> This error is enabled by default. It can be disabled by setting
> skipUnknownTags to true.
>
> To ignore errors about tags without declaring them to the TypeScript
> type system, you can add them to globalTags, however it is almost
> always a better idea to declare a type instead.

Source: https://lit.tools/unknown-tag